# Load data with two select

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have two select for my countylist and provincelist. I want when my page is open countrylist selected value "231"(mu country ıd) and my provinces get province ıd and load.. after when country select selected changed load province with selected country ıd. my code

```html
$('#CountryId').change(function () {
    $('#ProvinceId').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#preloader').fadeIn(200);
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProvinces/")' + $('#CountryId').val(), function (data) {var items = "";
        items += "<option value='' disabled selected>Seçim Yapın..</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            items += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + (item.Name) + "</option>";
        });
        $("#ProvinceId").html(items);
        $('#ProvinceId').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#preloader').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your controller action 'GetProvinces' code as well.

Comment: Mycontroller and province are works ı want make it in when document load.

Comment: ı want make it in when document load.  and use one funtion. when select get selected ıd when load get value 213

Comment: my english bad sory

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the change event after you set the value:

```
$('#CountryId').change(function() {
  // same code as in question

// set value and trigger change
}).val('231').change();
```